# DHCP server on Azure portal

Tags: azure, ip, dhcp

I’m working on Azure portal to create virtual machines with bastion and I was wondering, can I use DHCP server for internal IP addresses? I’m not sure it is possible because when I create a machine it already has an internal IP.

Answer (score 2):

DHCP by default does not exist in Microsoft Azure.
Or you may call it as vNet.
Just like you create a "Scope" of IP addresses in DHCP in an on-premesis environment, similarly, in Azure, you create "Subnet" in "vNet" and then when you create a VM and attach a vNet to it then the IP address is assigned from that subnet.

In simpler terms (not exact terms), you can say that:
vNet -> DHCP
Subnet -> Scope

I just wrote above relation in simpler terms so that you are able to understand it easily.

Answer (score 0):

That's what Azure Virtual Networks is for. Take a look at their documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-overview

Comment: I read the documentation and I’m not sure it answer my question. I know that while creating virtual environment I should create virtual network with ip range. But when I create a machine it takes IP from the range automatically. I want to create DHCP Virtual machine server on Azure that will share IPs address to the other machines in the domain.